# Cannot reach HTTP server on Android from another device when two WiFi STAs are connected (local-only and internet)

Tags: android, serversocket, httpserver, wifimanager, android-12

I have an app that creates a simple server to provide a file to connected IoT devices.
The flow is quite simple:

1. app connects to the WiFi network the IoT device creates (local-only, no internet access) - when it connects to the IoT WiFi network it disconnects from the previous WiFi network
2. app binds its process to the IoT device network
3. app starts a simple HTTP server to provide a file to devices on the IoT device network
4. app informs the IP and Port the server is running to the other devices
5. other devices access the server and download the file

Before Android 12, this flow worked 100% of the time.

But with the introduction of [WiFi STA/STA concurrency](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/wifi-sta-sta-concurrency) the app remains connected to the previous network (with an internet connection) and for some reason, the other devices on the IoT network never reach the HTTP server running on the Android app.

I'm still binding the process to the correct network, but the server only seems reachable once the primary WiFi network (the one with internet connection) is manually disconnected.

Is there something I'm missing to get the Android HTTP server running on the secodary WiFi network?

PS.: I'm using [NanoHTTPD](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd) to create the HTTP server, which creates a `ServerSocket` to serve the requests. I'm also using a Pixel 6 that supports the concurrent WiFi STA/STA feature.

Comment: Your http server aka NanoHttp runs on your device. Not on a network. NanoHttp has no idea about wifi or mobile connection and will accept connections from wifi, mobile or from a client on the device itself. What you perceived is that an Android device rather connects to a station with internet then one without.

Comment: `I'm still binding the process to the correct network,` I have no idea what you mean by that. And further i wonder why you would wanna bind your process to something.

Comment: `app connects to the WiFi network the IoT device creates..` That i do not understand. I would think your Android device would connect to a network.

Comment: `app informs the IP and Port the server is running to the other devices` How is it possible that your app can do that? Pretty vague.